# How to get number of days between two dates in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the number of days between 2 date from history booking room from one customer in SQL Server. The data has 3 status - in, stay and out.

Sample data:

```
id | room  | status |   date
---+-------+--------+------------
1  |   A   |   In   | 2018-01-10
2  |   A   |   Stay | 2018-01-11
3  |   A   |   out  | 2018-01-12
4  |   B   |   In   | 2018-01-12
5  |   B   |   Stay | 2018-01-13
6  |   B   |   Out  | 2018-01-14
7  |   A   |   In   | 2018-01-14
8  |   A   |   Stay | 2018-01-15
9  |   A   |   Stay | 2018-01-16
10 |   A   |   Out  | 2018-01-17
```

I expect the result for that customer, number of days in room A is 7 days and in room B is 3 days.

I already try to use min and max but the result is not valid because in the data that customer in the end is back to room A again

For the query I use

```
SELECT
    DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(a.LogDate), MAX(a.LogDate)) 
FROM
    CustomerLog a   
WHERE
    a.roomCode = 'A005' 
    AND a.RegistrationID = 298268
```

But for that problem then I need to change my query but I don't know how to get the second date for status 'IN' in room A also to get second date for status 'Out' in room A

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry. thx for the advice

Comment: Are you sure , for Room A it is 7.?  Result should be either A=7 and B=2 or A=8 and B=3, right?

Answer (score 0):

The `status` values seem to be irrelevant, and since you have a row for each day that a room is occupied, a simple count of distinct `date` values for each room will do. I applied distinct so that a check-in on the same day as a check-out does not get counted twice (in case that might occur).

The resulting query:

```
SELECT room, COUNT(distinct date) as DaysOccupied
FROM theTable
GROUP BY room
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Group by, Aggregate min & max and datediff function**

**Sample table and data**

```
declare @roombookingdata table
(id int ,room varchar(1), status varchar(10), recorddate date)

insert into @roombookingdata
(id , room  , status ,   recorddate)
values
(1  ,   'A'   ,   'In'   , '2018-01-10'),
(2  ,   'A'   ,   'Stay ', '2018-01-11'),
(3  ,   'A'   ,   'out'  , '2018-01-12'),
(4  ,   'B'   ,   'In'   , '2018-01-12'),
(5  ,   'B'   ,   'Stay' , '2018-01-13'),
(6  ,   'B'   ,   'Out'  , '2018-01-14'),
(7  ,   'A'   ,   'In'   , '2018-01-14'),
(8  ,   'A'   ,   'Stay' , '2018-01-15'),
(9  ,   'A'   ,   'Stay' , '2018-01-16'),
(10 ,   'A'   ,   'Out'  , '2018-01-17')
```

**Query**

```
select room, DateDiff(d, min(recorddate) , max(recorddate) ) as NooFDays, min(recorddate) as mindate, max(recorddate) as maxDate
from @roombookingdata
group by room
```